# Removing duplicates in fixed width file which has multiple key columns except the last occurrence

Tags: linux, shell, awk, text-processing

I have a fixed width file like below, where 1-9 and 18-21 are the key. Depending on which I am trying to get the output file without duplicate.

```
In File
12345ABCD78.90200ABCD
12345ABCD90.45300ABCD
11111EFGH56.75100ABCD
12345ABCD34.45400ABCD
11111EFGH75.90200ABCD

Out File
12345ABCD34.45400ABCD
11111EFGH75.90200ABCD
```

I have Tried using awk as below but not able to get the last occurrence of the duplicate. Can anyone help more on this.

```
awk -v df=Duplicates_File.dat -v of=Output_wdout_Duplicate.dat '
(substr($0, 1, 18),substr($0, 174, 3)) in key {
        print > df
        next
}
{       key[substr($0, 1, 18),substr($0, 174, 3)]
        print > of
}' Inputfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '{arr[substr($0,1,9),substr($0,18,4)]=$0} END{for(i in arr){print arr[i]}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, creating arr with index of 1st 9 characters and 18th to 21st characters and having current line value in it; keep doing same till whole Input_file is done with reading. In `END` block of this program printing all elements of array, which will basically provide all elements last occurrence only.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `awk`'s `FIELDSWIDTH` option you can try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS = "9 8 4 *"} {arr[$1,$3]=$0} END{for(i in arr){print arr[i]}}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use this `gnu sub` solution:

```sh
awk '{last[gensub(/^(.{9}).{8}(.{4}).*/, "\\1\\2", "1")] = $0} END {for (i in last) print last[i]}' file

11111EFGH75.90200ABCD
12345ABCD34.45400ABCD
```